# Update Database with Ajax and Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asmx

I have been trying to update using Ajax and Linq, but the Ajax call never gets to the webmethod of the code behind. I have changed the user class to match the database and made the user object the same names and still never gets to the code behind. I wonder if this is the preferred way?

Front page:

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txt_pass" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_item" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <asp:ListItem Text="item 1" Value="Item1" Selected="True"/>
            <asp:ListItem Text="item 2" Value="Item2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="item 3" Value="Item3" />
           </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_submit" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="GO"/>
</div>
```

userUpload.js

```
$(function() {
$('#btn_submit').on('click', function() {
    var user = {};
    user.name = $('#txt_name').val();
    user.Pass = $('#txt_pass').val();
    user.Item = $('#ddl_item').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "~/uploadUserAjax/SaveUser",
        data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            alert("user has been added");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

uploadUserAjax.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static void SaveUser(WebformTest.Models.User user)
    {
        using (var db = new dbDataContext())
        {
            var insert = new User
            {
                name = user.name,
                pass = user.pass,
                Item = user.Item
            };
            db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(insert);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

User class file:

```
 public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

my database file names are the same as my User class file.

I have changed these a few times and after doing lots of googling it says to keep your class file name the same as your js object file names, I am using the correct class file when passing in my setters for the values to be entered into the database. Wondered how i could check that it goes to the webmethod on the code behind. I haver all the correct using statements referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most likely caused by:

```
url: "~/uploadUserAjax/SaveUser"
```

`jQuery` doesn't know of `~`, only `ASP.NET` does.

You could have easily detected this issue by using the browser's included `developer tools`. You can check the network and/or console tabs for transport and/or JS errors. These developer tools are available in all modern browsers (Chrome, FF, IE8+) and you can open them by pressing `F12`.

Additionally you should debug the ASP.NET website itself using `Visual Studio`'s integrated `debugging` tools. This way you can test if the `WebMethod` is entered.

In `jQuery` you are using `$('#btn_submit')` but asp.net generates another ID for that button. Consider replacing the button with a normal HTML one. Or just use `$('#<%=btn_submit.ClientID %>')`.

Comment: @Url.Content can be used to translate your tilde notation.

Comment: The webmethod is never entered, i have a break ppoint and I am stepping through the program even debugginhg in I.E through the javascript.

Comment: in jQuery you are using $('#btn_submit') but asp.net generates another ID for that button. Consider replacing the button with a normal HTML one.

Comment: Or just use $('#<%=btn_submit.ClientID %>')

Comment: I have the ClientModeId as Static and all the info is in the USer object just doesn't seem to break into the uploadUserAjax code behind page

Comment: That doesn't achieve what you want. Have you checked the raw HTML? If If you want identifiers to be how you name them with no change, you'll want to use the `Predictable` mode, I think.

Comment: I have done it I changed the name of the file to  url: "/uploadUserAjax.aspx/SaveUser", and it has worked. thank you for helping it was something to do with the URL.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu `ClientIdMode="static"` will use the same ID on the client and the server. No need to use Predictable.

Comment: Just a note, you can also do `$("[id$=btn_submit]")`, the selector here *is* not as performant, but it works.